# RequestError throwing while sending data to Elasticsearch using Kafka and Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

My topic name is mytopic. My consumer is able to produce the JSON data from the csv. My CSV is below

```
owner,Rank,Model,mileage,priceincrore,torque
maws,1,Audi,20,2,7000
drav,2,Benz,23,3,8000
ere,3,Ford,12,1,5400
```

My python Code is below

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
import datetime

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}]) 
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
   'mytopic',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    enable_auto_commit=True)


for val in kafkaconsumer:
    current_values = loads(val.value)
    es.index(index='esindex', doc_type='my_type',id=1, body=current_values)
```

> logger.warning('Undecodable raw error response from server: %s', err)
>    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')

Comment: Your index is empty? if not please check the mapping with your document you want to insert

Comment: Suggestion: Have you tried using Kafka Elasticsearch connector instead? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/

Comment: You can also not write any Python at all and use Kafka Conncet entirely to read a CSV, which writes to a topic, and then send to Elastic - https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir